# Building a variable depth hash reference data structure in perl

Tags: perl

I needed to build a variable depth hash data structure in perl.  Eventually I found this piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash;
my $value = "foo";
my @cats = qw(a b c d);

my $p = \%hash;
foreach my $item (@cats) {
 $p->{$item} = {} unless exists($p->{$item});
 $p = $p->{$item};
}
```

My question is how and why it works.  I thought I knew how perl worked.  At no point in this code do I see \%hash value being reset and it appears that $p (which is a local variable) is reset on every loop.  I could even see it with data dumper:
Running:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my $value = "foo";
my @cats = qw(a b c d);

my $p = \%hash;
foreach my $item (@cats) {
 print "BEFORE:\n";
 print Dumper(\%hash);
 #print Dumper($p);
 $p->{$item} = {} unless exists($p->{$item});
 $p = $p->{$item};
 print "AFTER:\n";
 print Dumper(\%hash);
 #print Dumper($p);
}
```

And Then uncommenting the line with

```
#print Dumper($p)
```

CLEARLY shows $p being a new variable every time.

How does \%hash gets build if $p is reset every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$p` isn't being "reset" each time; it's being set to the next lower level in the hash, the one just added. At this point it is just an empty hashref, `{}`, because it will be filled in on the next loop iteration.

I'm not sure how you are concluding that `$p` is a new variable each time, but this is incorrect.. it's just pointing to a new location in the `%hash` structure.  Since it was declared outside the loop, it doesn't lose its value as the loop iterates.

Answer (score 1):

Add an explicit marker to the hash to which `$p` refers:

```
 ...
 print "AFTER:\n";
 $p->{'$p'} = 'is here!';
 print Dumper(\%hash);
 delete $p->{'$p'};
}
```

Then the last couple of AFTER dumps look like

```
AFTER:
$VAR1 = {
  'a' => {
    'b' => {
      'c' => {
        '$p' => 'is here!'
      }
    }
  }
};

AFTER:
$VAR1 = {
  'a' => {
    'b' => {
      'c' => {
        'd' => {
          '$p' => 'is here!'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Yes, at each new depth, `$p` refers to an empty hash, but take a step back to see the overall structure of `%hash`.

Answer (score 1):

Wanna see something cool? This does the same thing (only you never see it assign the *hashref*!)

```
my $p = \\%hash; # $p is a reference to a hashref
foreach my $item (@cats) {
    # because $p references a reference, you have to dereference
    # it to point to the hash.
    $p = \$$p->{$item} unless exists $$p->{$item};
}
```

The slot is [autovivified](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#autovivification) as soon as you reference it, and when it gets addressed like a hashref, it creates that hashref.